# Product and product template in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

What is the need for two different tables for Product Master in Odoo ? 
How product.product and product.template differ ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. You should ask that in [Odoo Help Forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has absolutely nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Do Googling!!
Here is the links which are useful:  https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/product-template-vs-product-product-94430  &   https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/1198

Comment: This is a relevant question to Odoo programming. Product.product and product.template are in addition to tables, also Odoo models for programming. These models are ambiguously named and answer to this question will clarify usage.

Comment: @CZoellner I tried.. My questions are never answered on Odoo Forums !!!
@ Veikko That helped a lot...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Odoo has two models/tables for products because of product variants:

- product.product contains variant level information.
- product.template contains information that is same to all variants.

You can use product variants in Odoo by turning on "Products can have several attributes, defining variants" in Sales / Settings. With variants the product.template contains the main product (e.g. T-Shirt) and product.product contains the variants (e.g. T-Shirt size M, T-Shirt size L,...).

If you do not use variants, these two models and tables have almost the same content.

You can find more information on Odoo product variant from https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/10.0/ecommerce/managing_products/variants.html.